# How to retrieve online database data from multiple perl script

Tags: perl, phpmyadmin

I have a working Perl script which will insert, retrieve data from a mysql database correctly when I do with my system and no problem in script.

I have db which contains 10000 line of data with two attributes id, url.

I have to open the db using Perl and take the first 10 datasets of id and url in my machine, and in another system it should take next 10 line of data like that i have to do for five separate machine simultaneously.

Is there anyway to do like this or any other method?

Comment: I understand that you want different programs to work together on the same set of data. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, same script that should works in different machines and retrieve data from single database

Comment: There is no problem to run the same program on different machines, and have them all use the same database. What's interesting is to get them to process something in parallel. It sounds like you want to cluster your data processing. Machine a will do lines 1 to 10, machine B will do lines 11 to 20 and so on. The question now is, how do they know which ones to run? If there is a static assignment, you could use arguments to your programs.

Comment: what you said is exactly correct and that is my problem , if I run the same script in all system it take first 10 data and it became duplicate values, how to avoid it.

Comment: Do you know beforehand which system should get what chunk of the data? Or do you just want all data processed, but it takes a while to process the data, and each client should take some, process it, and then take the next chunk?

Comment: I don't know but its not problem , I should take 10 new line of data that should not present in any other script. After process 10 line it should take next 10 new line.

Comment: It sounds a bit like what you want is a queue. Can you tell me more about the real application? What kind of data is this, and how long does processing take? Is this a learning exercise or a real-world problem? The approach we will take depends on that.

Comment: It's a bit long time process, we check whether the url is working or not

Comment: Does your database user have write access to the database? Can you write data back? I think a valid approach would be to add a field to the table that holds whether this line has been processed already, and update it before you start processing in each script. So you would first select the first 10 unprocessed ones, then fill in that field in those, then process them, and repeat. If you need to process them regularly, you could either reset the field before you begin, or work with timestamps and a certain time-frame. It's like a queue, but it's not 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your script with a parameter telling it it is number 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5. So same script, just called with another number on each of the 5 hosts. So number 1 processes 1-10, 51-60, 101-110 and so on, you get it. This will work correctly as long as no (id,url) pairs are deleted or inserted. Appending is ok. If your scripts write log files, you can always see how far the done. You could even add a 'host' and a 'status' column to your table, indicating wether a record is not processed yet, being processed by which host or done already.

If you can't add columns to the existing table, you might use a second table referencing to the first table by the id.

If you want to go fancy and solve the insert/delete problem (in case it applies to you), you can go one step further and make your hosts check for the next unprocessed record, lock it, process it, write status to 'done', then release the record.

Then you can even dynamically have hosts join the party and lock,process,release records just as they have resources available.

====================

Different start: one host is controller and distributes your 10-record packets. So the equal script on each host has to accept a parameter transporting 10 ids. A second script notices, when a host is done with it's 10 records and gives it 10 fresh ones.

Happy scripting.

TomTomTom

Comment: Sorry for late reply, by your method i got the solution but if i increase the number of simultaneously connection 5 to 100 . Now I'm doing like this when 100 Connection connected to single db and once the work finished, it will lock the table and update the result to db.  Now the problem is when we lock the table the remaining connection waits when the table will unlock is there any method to do with type

Comment: Locking the whole table is only required for entire-table operations. Just lock the reckord(s) you are going to modify (and unlock when you are done), so other records are free to be modified simultaneously.